# How do I set my label to be visible even when the Layout is null? Also, JFrame size still defaults to the minimum

Tags: java, layout, jframe, jbutton, jlabel

This is what my code looks like at the moment:

```
public TestFrame(){
    setSize(x1, y1); /*where these are already defined*/
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JLabel label = new JLabel("text");
    label.setBorders(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
    label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", PLAIN, 14));
    label.setSize(width, height);
    label.setLocation(x, y)
    /* where these four variables are already defined */
    JButton testButton = new JButton("TestButton");
    testButton.setSize(bwidth, bheight);
    testButton.setLocation(bx, by);
    add(label);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

This is mainly giving me the problem that, since this is a FlowLayout, it sets the size of the TestFrame to the minimum, and doesn't put the label or the button in their correct sizes or locations.
I was told that I need to set my layout to null, as so:

```
setLayout(null);
```

The main problem here is that while this does put the button exactly where it should be, it does not automatically set the size of the TestFrame to the specified size, and while the label was visible, displaying the correct font and size of said font, with borders surrounding the entire text, setting the layout to null makes the label disappear entirely for some reason.

Is there an explanation as to why it disappears entirely? How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing setSize and setLocation with setBounds(x,y,width,height);
The null Layout is quite weird and I would recommend you to use LayoutManagers.

Answer (score 0):

> since this is a FlowLayout it sets the size of the TestFrame to the minimum,

No, a FlowLayout will respect the preferred size of each component.

> doesn't put the label or the button in their correct sizes or locations.

That is because the structure of your code is wrong. You are using the setSize(...) method which means the layout managers can't do their job properly.

The basic structure of your code should be:

```
setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
...
add(label);
...
add(button);
pack(); // this will invoke the layout managers and size the frame correctly.
setVisible(true);
```